# How to type Persian in Python compiler

Tags: python, python-3.x, farsi

When I try to type Persian in Python, I get this:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: That is not Python's fault, it is your editor (cmd in this case). Try that same thing in IDLE and it will work fine. Or some other IDE (PyCharm, VSCode, etc).

Comment: I can also recommend the Jupyter Notebook project.

Comment: Nima are you interested in a job in tehran?